# What is the difference in Git between being in a directory (cd) and using the `work-tree` parameter?

Tags: git, git-worktree

I am using PHP to run Git in PHP's `exec` to get some information about some Git projects for a set of server dashboards. I have encountered some strange output, which makes me wonder if I misunderstand what the "working tree" is.

If I use this command, replacing the `%s` sprintf parameter with the path to the Git project:

```
git --work-tree=%s status
```

Then I get this output:

```
On branch server-dashboard
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/server-dashboard' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    deleted:    README.md
    deleted:    common.php
    deleted:    conf/dev/settings.ini
    deleted:    conf/prod/settings.ini
    deleted:    conf/settings.ini.example
    deleted:    lib/HealthSettings.php
    deleted:    lib/Settings.php
    deleted:    public/assets/main.css
    deleted:    public/assets/main.js
    deleted:    public/assets/refresh.gif
    deleted:    public/assets/spinner.gif
    deleted:    public/curl-test.php
    deleted:    public/dashboard.php
    deleted:    public/iframes.php
    modified:   public/index.php
    deleted:    public/info.php
    deleted:    public/no-servers.php
    deleted:    public/sections/apache-mods.php
    deleted:    public/sections/curl-headers.php
    deleted:    public/sections/curl-self.php
    deleted:    public/sections/database.php
    deleted:    public/sections/env.php
    deleted:    public/sections/git-table.php
    deleted:    public/sections/git.php
    deleted:    public/sections/php-exts.php
    deleted:    public/sections/php-proxy.php
    deleted:    public/sections/tableau-proxy-table.php
    deleted:    public/sections/tableau-proxy.php
    deleted:    public/sections/user.php
    deleted:    public/tabs.php
```

That is not what I expect, since it is not what I get if I run `git status` on the console.

Now, if I run this command in PHP (again swapping the string param for a path):

```
cd %s && git status
```

then I get the correct output:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 17 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I am guessing that since this project is 17 commits behind master, the "wrong"  output in fact is an expression of what has changed over those commits. However, I would have thought the two commands would be equivalent. Am I wrong, and if so, can I run a Git command programmatically without having to `cd` first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of substantive differences between `cd path; git command` and `git --work-tree=path command`.  Some or all of these differences can be made to vanish depending on *additional* parameters and/or environment variables.

It's important to realize that Git has three (not just two) key items that it must work with at almost all times.  These are:

- The repository itself (the repo database of name-to-hash-ID pairs, such as `master` representing commit `e3331758f12da22f4103eec7efe1b5304a9be5e9` or whatever other hash ID, plus the object whose ID is that big ugly hash ID string).  The repository typically lives in a directory named `.git` at the top level of the work-tree.  This is the *git directory* (`$GIT_DIR`).
- The *index*, which indexes and caches (hence its two names *index* or sometimes *cache*) the work-tree, and acts as a storage location (hence its third name, *staging area*) for updated files (really, pathname to blob hash ID translations) when you intend to build a new commit.  The index is mostly a file: `.git/index`.  As you can see from this path name, by default, the index file lives within the repository.  However, it has its own separate control variable, `$GIT_INDEX_FILE`.  It simply *defaults* to `$GIT_DIR/index`.
- The *work-tree* holds files in their uncompressed format.  Files make their way *into* the work-tree by being extracted from a commit into the index, and then from the index (where they're still compressed and in Git-only format) into the work-tree.  The work-tree may also hold additional files that are not found in the index.  Such files are *unstaged*.  An unstaged file may or may not be *ignored* (a staged file, i.e., one whose pathname appears in the index, is by definition never ignored).

The work-tree is normally just the current working directory, or derived from the current working directory by walking upwards (`..`, then `../..`, and so on) to find the first place that contains a `.git` repository directory.  This means that `cd path; git ...` searches for the work-tree starting from wherever you have landed.

If there are no overrides, having found the work-tree and hence the `.git` directory, Git now knows where `$GIT_DIR` is and where to find the index file.  But if you provide an override, using `git --work-tree=path` or by setting the environment variable `$GIT_WORK_TREE`, Git will look there for the work-tree, and look in the current directory (or `..` and then `../..` and so on) for the repository directory.

If you provide a `--git-dir=path` override, or set the environment variable `$GIT_DIR`, Git will look *there* for the repository directory, regardless of any setting or lack of setting for the work-tree.

(Note: `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` are actually implemented by having the `git` front end set the environment variables.  Hence if you set *both*, the flag argument overrides the environment setting for the duration of the Git command, including any subprocesses that Git itself runs.)

IF you provide a `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` override via the environment, Git will look *there* for the index file, regardless of any setting or lack of setting for `$GIT_DIR`.

Any of these settings can be an *absolute path*—starting with `/` on Unix-like systems, or using a drive letter on sillier systems—or a *relative path*.  An absolute path overrides the current working directory, while a relative path starts from the current working directory.

Hence the exact contents of any of these arguments or environment variables matter a great deal.  For instance, running:

```
cd $HOME/foo; GIT_INDEX_FILE=$HOME/index git --git-dir=sub/.git --work-tree=/tmp ...
```

will cause Git to look for the *repository* in `$HOME/foo/sub/.git`, the *index file* in `$HOME/index`, and the *work-tree* in /tmp.

Besides all of this, the front-end `git` command allows a `-C` argument, or multiple `-C` arguments.  Each of these makes Git execute a `cd` to the supplied path.  Hence the above is largely equivalent to:

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$HOME/index git -C $HOME/foo --git-dir=sub/.git --work-tree=/tmp ...
```

except that once the above command terminates, your shell / command-interpreter remains in whatever working directory it had before you ran the command.  (These details vary slightly on Windows, I believe, since Windows makes some very strange assumptions about "current directory" vs "current drive letter", or something along those lines.)

---

In your specific case—running `git status`—be aware that `git status` does two separate comparisons:

- First, it compares (a la `git diff`) the *current commit* (found via `$GIT_DIR/HEAD`) to the contents of `$GIT_INDEX_FILE`.  Whatever is different here is *staged for commit*.
- Then it compares (again a la `git diff`) the contents of the index file to the contents of `$GIT_WORK_TREE`.  Whatever is different here is *not staged for commit*.

The ahead and/or behind counts come from an earlier step, where `git status` uses the current branch (again from `$GIT_DIR/HEAD`).  Normally, this `HEAD` file is a symbolic reference, containing the name of the current branch.  Git can then find that branch's *upstream* setting (`git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name $branch@{upstream}`, more or less, though `--abbrev-ref` is more suitable for humans): `master` typically has `refs/remotes/origin/master` as its upstream.  Git then reads through the commit graph, extracted from `$GIT_DIR`, to discover how many commits ahead and/or behind `master` is vs `origin/master`.

---

The above is not the whole story.  Consult the [git front end command documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html) to find a more complete list of environment variables that can be used to override specific items.  For instance, `GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES` can be used to make Git look outside the repository itself for additional object storage locations, while `GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES` can be used to limit the amount of path-walking Git does when looking through `..`, `../..`, and so on.

Comment: This is a marvellous answer, for which many thanks. I've been meaning to peek at some Git internals just to improve my understanding of data structures, and this is a great start.

Comment: However, my one remaining confusion is: since I am using the Git frontend, it strikes me that the index and the Git dir could be derived from the work tree, since the `.git` folder's default position is in the root of the work tree. Why does the front end not derive these automatically? I wonder if it is using its current `cd` path to (wrongly) fill in the gaps. Since I am running this command in LAMP, I'd guess the cwd is the location of the script I am running.

Comment: One thing to look out for is whether `$GIT_DIR` is *already set*, which it is in (most? all?) hook scripts. If it's not set, then yes, Git does the search-for-`.git` based on current-working-directory.

Comment: Right. So if my cwd is set to something essentially random, then specifying the work tree via a parameter is not enough. Thanks - I am relieved that Git is not broken, even on Windows `;-)`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer complicates things with a discussion of environment variables that will never be set in practice when running a php server script and it doesn't clearly answer which option solves the problem. Let's try:

```sh
$ cd
$ ls -ad .git
ls: cannot access '.git': No such file or directory

$ env | grep -i git | wc -l
0

$ git --work-tree=$HOME/myrepo describe --always
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

$ git --work-tree=$HOME/myrepo --git-dir=$HOME/myrepo/.git describe --always
d5cd316

$ git --git-dir=$HOME/myrepo/.git describe --always
d5cd316

$ git --git-dir=$HOME/myrepo describe --always
fatal: not a git repository: '/home/redacted/myrepo'
```

--> `--git-dir` is enough but it needs the `/.git` suffix.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's nice to have several answers that tackle a problem in different ways. I am technically still working on the project for which I needed this, on and off, so maybe I will have cause to use this useful advice!